# why minizip doesn't archive large file (larger 4 GB)

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, zlib, large-files

I am trying to use **static minizip** library on Windows 7 64-bit, using Visual Studio 2010.
**The main goal is to archive files larger 4GB.**
I build zlib using CMake 2.8, and linked in to my project.
**It works for files less 4GB, but doesn't work proper for files larger 4GB.**
Why I have a problem with archiving 5GB file using minizip?
Did I miss something on the build libraries stage?
**Here are all my steps, library and project:** [https://github.com/koponomarenko/file_compression](https://github.com/koponomarenko/file_compression/archiver_minizip/Archive.cpp)

Really need help. Thanks.

**Updated:**

***"doesn't work proper for files larger 4GB"*** means that my test program archives 5GB txt file without any errors during this process. I checked **zipWriteInFileInZip()** returns **ZIP_OK** for all 5,368,709,120 bytes. **zipCloseFileInZip()** and **zipClose()** don't return any errors. But in created archive (I use 7-zip) file info is:

- **Uncompressed size:** 4,294,967,295
- **Compressed size:** 8,806,676
- **Attributes:** *empty field*
- **CRC:** 81970625
- **Method:** Deflate
- **Host OS:** FAT
- **Version:** 45

And I get error message "Unsupported compression method" when try to unzip (using 7-zip) this archive.

**I also zipped the same 5GB txt file with 7-zip**. Here is file info from this archive:

- **Uncompressed size:** 5,368,709,120
- **Compressed size:** 9,608,471
- **Attributes:** A
- **CRC:** 81970625
- **Method:** Deflate
- **Host OS:** FAT
- **Version:** 45

The first 3 fields are different from my archive.

**Updated:**

```
void Archive::create()
{
     m_archiveHandle = zipOpen64(m_sName.c_str(), APPEND_STATUS_CREATE);

     if ( !m_archiveHandle )
     {
         throw Error("Can't create the archive. Can be already created.");
     }
}

void Archive::add(string sSrcFile, string sDstFile)
{
    //////////////////////////// create a file
    zip_fileinfo zfi;
    memset(&zfi, 0, sizeof(zfi));
    int zip64 = 1;
    int ret = zipOpenNewFileInZip64(m_archiveHandle,
        sDstFile.c_str(),
        &zfi,
        NULL, 0,
        NULL, 0,
        "my comment for this interior file",
        Z_DEFLATED,
        Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION,
        zip64
        );
    if ( ret != 0 )
    {
        throw Error("Can't add file to a zip archive.");
    }


    //////////////////////////// write to the file
    FILE * pFile = fopen( sSrcFile.c_str(), "rb" );
    if ( !pFile )
    {
        throw Error("Can't open target file.");
    }

    char * buf = new char[BUF_SIZE];
    int size_read = 0;
    int err;
    do
    {
        err = ZIP_OK;
        size_read = (int)fread(buf, 1, BUF_SIZE, pFile);
        if (size_read < BUF_SIZE)
            if ( feof(pFile) == 0 )
            {
                err = ZIP_ERRNO;
            }

            if (size_read > 0)
            {
                err = zipWriteInFileInZip (m_archiveHandle, buf, size_read);
            }
    } while ((err == ZIP_OK) && (size_read>0));

    delete [] buf;

    //////////////////////////// close the file
    if ( zipCloseFileInZip(m_archiveHandle) != 0 )
    {
        throw Error("Can't close added file.");
    }
}


void Archive::close()
{
    if ( !m_archiveHandle )
        return;

    if ( zipClose(m_archiveHandle, "my comment for exterior file") != 0)
    {
        throw Error( "Can't save changes and close." );
    }

    m_archiveHandle = 0;
}
```

I use this batch file to get static Zlib. I put it in *zlib/build64* and run from *"Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt"*.

```
rem ** go to the current script directory
cd %~dp0

cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 10 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\devel\installed\zlib64"
msbuild /P:Configuration=Debug INSTALL.vcxproj
msbuild /P:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj
```

**Updated:**

Created archive can be unzipped by Total Commander and Windows Explorer. I compared a check-sum (md5, sha1) of the original file and unzipped file, and it was the same. But neither Total nor Explorer shows attributes of the compressed file. Meanwhile 7-zip says me "Unsupported compression method".

**Updated December 09, 2013:**

It seems that minizip has some problems with attributes when work with files larger 4GB on Windows. 7-Zip and WinZip can't unzip created archive.

Comment: Is it a 64 bit projekt? Do you have enough free (heap) memory?

Comment: I added x64 configuration in Config Manger in project. I have 8GB RAM.

Comment: Are you using a version of minizip which supports a version of the zip format that actually supports files > 4GB?

Comment: I am using the latest (1.2.8) version of zlib and included into this library minizip (zlib/contrib/minizip). Assume that version of minizip in zlib/contrib is also the latest version.

Comment: Does minizip support >32 bit file sizes at all?

Comment: There is a mention on the official minizip site that it supports Zip64 extension starting from 1.1 version. That's why I suppose it does.

Comment: When it "doesn't work proper for files larger 4GB", what happens?

Comment: I added more info to my question above.

Comment: You need to put code in your question and not simply link to code hosted on an external (to SO) site.

Comment: I've made changes following your advice.

Comment: Your problem looks like a bug to me that need be reported to the minizip developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in order of fields (extra field and file comment field) for Central Directory Record in ZIP. So if your file is bigger than 4GB and you added a comment for it you are going to face this bug.

It seems to me that the original author stopped maintenance this library, but I found a repo with some fresh changes on Github here https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip . So I wrote about this bug to the author of this repo.